# Why crontab change signal handle behavior of a process?

Tags: c, signals, solaris, cron

Below is a very simple C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
        sleep(100);
        return 0;
}
```

After building and run it on `Solaris 10`, using `psig` to check the signal behaviors of the process:

```
bash-3.2# psig 21429
21429:  ./test
HUP     default
INT     default
QUIT    default
......
RTMAX   default
```

All the signal process behaviors are `default`, and it is right.

Then I configure the program in `crontab`:

```
23 * * * * /data1/nan/test
```

When the program is started from `crontab`, and I use `psig` check the signal behaviors again:

```
bash-3.2# psig 21452
21452:  /data1/nan/test
HUP     ignored
INT     ignored
QUIT    ignored
......
TSTP    ignored
......
TTIN    ignored
TTOU    ignored
......
```

I find some signal behaviors are changed from `default` to `ignored`. I try to find the answers from `crontab` manual, but nothing valuable is found.

Could some give some clues about this issue? Thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The child processes of `cron` inherit the signal dispositions from their parent, `cron`.

The Solaris man page for [`fork(2)`](http://www.manpages.info/sunos/fork.2.html) says:

> The  child  process  inherits  the following attributes from the parent process:
>
> - signal handling settings (that is,  SIG_DFL,  SIG_IGN,
>            SIG_HOLD, function address)

Comment: After using `ps -ef | grep 28332`, it displays: `root 28333 28332   0 14:01:01 ?           0:00 /data1/nan/test
root 28332   315   0 14:01:01 ?           0:00 sh -c /data1/nan/test`. The pid of `cron` is 315, and the parent of `test` is `sh`, so the `test` should inherits the signal dispositions of `sh`, right?

Comment: Yes, but the parent of `sh` is probably `cron`. The shell is used by `system(3)` for example to execute commands.

Comment: Another question, when I execute `test` in the command line directly:`./test`, I find the signal handlers are all "`default`". But the parent of "./test" is `bash`. After using `psig 17894` (17984 is the pid of `bash`), it displays some signals are ignored by `bash` (e.g., SIGTTIN). Per my understanding, as the son of `bash`, the `SIGTTIN` handler of `test` should also be ignored, why is it not default?

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely due to inheritance of signal dispositions by the `fork()` call. It won't be inheriting from `crontab` (which is really just an admin interface into `cron`), rather it will inherit from `cron` itself.